# What must the file permissions be for x-sendfile to work with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, file-permissions

I have a Ruby-on-Rails application that I am hosting with Apache and Phusion-Passenger (on Ubuntu Server). In this app I have a controller method that basically protects access to some files based on the currently logged in user and then servers them using X-sendfile. The method looks something like this:

```
def show
     if File.exists @file_name
         sendfile @file_name, :xsendfile => true
     else
         render_404
     end
end
```

It mysteriously does not work on our staging server and I suspect It has something to do with file permissions because every time I hit it I get a 404 but it is not the 404 page that my would render as a result of my `render404` call; thus I suspect the error is occurring after the `sendfile` line is executed.

Could someone please clarify for me what must the file permissions be in order for apache to server something via x-sendfile.

PS I should also point out that I am quite sure that my X-sendfile module is properly configured and working so its nothing to do with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, it must be readable by the user the web server is running as.

Comment: Ya this should have been obvious... In the end the problem was that the group Apache was running as was not what I expected. I just learned about the envvars file... :s